# What is 'Assassin Strike'?

Tags: blades-of-time

I found a weapon a while ago that says it increases the effectiveness of something (an ability, presumably) called *Assassin Strike*.  I don't remember that term ever being used in the tutorial though, and I have no idea what it is referring to.  Anybody know?

[image: Increases effectiveness of Assassin Strike]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to an FAQ for Blades of Time

Assassin Strike is described as such:

> % Assassin's Strike
>
> Enemies lose part of their life force after being hit by the Heavy Strike

Also confirmed on the top left icon of the Blades of Time website

> http://www.bladesoftime.com/about/magic/